# How to show that $|\alpha-\beta|^p \le \max(1,2^{p-1})(|\alpha|^p+|\beta|^p)$ for complex $\alpha,\beta$ and $0<p<\infty$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, complex-numbers

First of all $\max(1,2^{p-1})$ equals to $1$ if $0<p \le 1$ and equals to $2^{p-1}$ if $1<p<\infty$. So we should discuss whether $p$ is greater than $1$ or not. For $0<p<1$ I was thinking about this:
$$
a^p+b^p \ge (a+b)^p
$$
for $a,b \ge 0$. If this approach is possible, how do I proceed? In this problem we are dealing with complex numbers, and there is a norm, I can't apply this directly.

For $p>1$, I was thinking about Newton expansion, but it's weird and I can find no way to proceed as well. Using derivatives would be great but again we are facing complex numbers with norm. Any solutions or hints? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alt. hint: the [generalized means inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Special_cases) $\;\frac{a+b}{2} \ge \sqrt[p]{\frac{a^p+b^p}{2}}\,$.

Answer (score 1):

**Only hints, not a complete solution**

Hint 1: An equivalent claim is that $|1 - u|^p \le \max(1, 2^{p-1})(1 + |u|^p)$, which you can see by setting $u = \frac{\beta}{\alpha}$. This reduces your problem to two variables instead of three.

Hint 2: (generalized) binomial theorem and triangle inequality.

Hint 3: Your approach where you split into the cases based on $p$ is a good idea.